# My computer restarts every time I open VMware software

Tags: macbook, vmware-fusion

I recently time machine backed up my MacBook and updated the operating system to Catalina. I have unblocked VM ware fusion as well. However every time I open app my computer restarts. How can I sort this? The app was purchased from my university so I sent have software to reinstall.

Comment: "so I sent have software to reinstall." - What?  Have you tried to install the current version of the software, downloaded directly from VMWare, which is easily reinstalled since you have the appropriate license key.

Comment: Also make sure you are using the 64-bit version of VMware Fusion as Catalina will not run 32-bit software (Catalina came out 64-bit only)